# How do you list the primary key of a SQL Server User Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is simple, how do you list the primary key (column name) of a SQL Server **User Defined Table Type**?

ex;

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [ID] int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID])
)
```

How to get the column `[ID]` with a query

It seem it is only possible to find primary key for real table, not table type.

Comment: The linked question doesn't address UDTs at all. Most likely this *is* a duplicate of another question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i didn't find one, this is why i'm asking it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm specifying that because many people would simply flag it as duplicate

Comment: Don't post a link to an unrelated question then. Besides, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are deprecated. Did you check the `sys.tables` and `sys.key_constraints` views? If you can find the information from there, then this is a duplicate of any question that asks about primary keys and the answer contains `sys.key_constraints`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I did check many sys.???? table to try finding primary key (column name) of a UDT

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i removed the link, let see how fast it will be flagged as duplicate

Comment: Why not get the PK of a table that was created using the type?  A type isn't a table.   It technically doesn't HAVE a Primary Key.   It just has code that will create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is stored in the catalog views:

```
SELECT  c.Name
FROM    sys.table_types AS tt
        INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints AS kc
            ON kc.parent_object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
            ON i.object_id = kc.parent_object_id
            AND i.index_id = kc.unique_index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
            ON ic.object_id = kc.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
            ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
            AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE   tt.Name = 'YourTypeName';
```

Answer (score 1):

A user-defined table isn't an actual table so it has an entry in `sys.table_types`, not in `sys.tables`.

The key information can be retrieved from `sys.key_constraints` as with other tables, if the `sys.table_types.type_table_object_id` and `sys.key_constraints.parent_object_id` fields are used, eg:

```
create TYPE TestTableType AS TABLE 
( 
    ID int primary key,
    Name nVARCHAR(50)
)

declare @typeID int

select @typeId=type_table_object_id 
from sys.table_types
where name='TestTableType'

select @typeId
-- Returns 1134627085

select * 
from sys.key_constraints
where parent_object_id=@typeID

-- Returns 
-- PK__TT_TestT__3214EC27BA14A4A6   1150627142  NULL    4   1134627085  PK  PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT  2016-04-25 17:36:34.890 2016-04-25 17:36:34.890 1   0   0   1   1
```

After that, you can get the column name in the same way as with other primary keys, by joining with `sys.index_columns` and `sys.columns`:

```
select col.name
from sys.key_constraints kcon
    inner join sys.index_columns indcol on indcol.object_id=kcon.parent_object_id
    inner join sys.columns col on col.object_id = kcon.parent_object_id 
               and col.column_id = indcol.column_id
where parent_object_id=@typeID
```

Or

```
select col.name
from sys.table_types tt 
    inner join sys.key_constraints kcon on type_table_object_id=kcon.parent_object_id
    inner join sys.index_columns indcol on indcol.object_id=kcon.parent_object_id
    inner join sys.columns col on col.object_id = kcon.parent_object_id and col.column_id = indcol.column_id
where tt.name='TestTableType'
```

Comment: this still doesn't give me the column name

Comment: @Fredou you added that requirement *after* I posted the answer

Comment: look at the edit history, it was specified on the original question, in the first line with the **(column name)**